# How can I open port 80?

Tags: firewall, iptables

I'm new in Ubuntu, and I'm trying to open port 80. I have already set my router in order to do so, and I also set ufw.

```
Status: active

     To                         Action      From

[ 1] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] 80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 3] 22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 4] 80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

But when I check localhost with Nmap, Port 80 is still closed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there anything actually listening on port 80? A webserver like apache or nginx? Post the output of `sudo netstat -lpn | grep :80`

Comment: Nope, it is just my computer. This is what I get with that command:

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8099  

        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3761/spotify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nmap` shows open ports if the server is *listening* on that port on the interface scanned. As you can see from the `netstat` output, no process is listening on port 80.

Comment: So I have my port 80 open, but because there isn't any process there is not an aswer to netstat or nmap to determine is open, am i right?

Comment: @Pepe yes, indeed. `netstat` uses different methods.

Comment: I dont know, if I have to open new topic but what can i do to run some webpage just in my network?

Thanks a lot for the fast replies!

Comment: @Pepe Check out the LTS server guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/web-servers.html, in particular the sections on Apache and PHP, and if you have problems, then you could ask new questions.